# Batch Obtain Usernames and PWD Expiration From AD

Tags: batch-file

I currently have a text file with all AD users on it. Using the following, I can get a piped list of expiration dates for PWD but I am unable to get the Username paired with the expiration for accurracy. Can anyone assist? Caveat: needs to be batch :(

```
        for /F %%i in (users.txt) do net user %%i /domain | find "Password expires" >> passwordexp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have all the info you need when you need it, you just need to print it out :-)

You can use parentheses to execute multiple commands in your DO clause.

You can use SET /P to print information without a newline at the end.

It is more efficient to enclose the entire construct in parentheses and direct the output to a file just once.

```
@echo off
(
  for /F %%i in (users.txt) do (
    <nul set /p "=%%i: "
    net user %%i /domain | find "Password expires"
  )
)>passwordexp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

ok  i think that this will work for you:

to get the "User name" do this:

```
    for /f "tokens=1-3*" %%a in ('net user administrator /domain ^| find "User name"') do @echo "%%a %%b" "%%c" & set uname=%%c
```

to get the "Password expires" do this:

```
    for /f "tokens=1-3*" %%a in ('net user administrator /domain ^| find "Passowrd expires"') do @echo "%%a %%b" "%%c" & set expires=%%c
```

to show the status of user, do this:

```
    echo %uname% expires %expires%
```

does that work for what you want (dont forget to change administrator to your user name)