# Bat file to only output 2 specific lines,

Tags: batch-file

Basically what I am trying to do is just create a simple batch file to show when user password was last set and will expire. the bat file displays a lot of info not revealed to the user. how would I go about doing only the "Password Last Set, Password expires"I tried to do it over PowerShell but the active directory module isn't available for the company I am with. 
I'm complete noob when it comes this stuff but anything would help. 
here is a simple bat file

```
@echo off
goto :input
:input
echo Press Enter To Continue:
echo[
set /p username=
net user %username% /domain
goto :input
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch Obtain Usernames and PWD Expiration From AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654783/batch-obtain-usernames-and-pwd-expiration-from-ad)

Comment: Use a for /f to parse output of net use filtered by a find/findstr.

Comment: You're telling the end user to press enter to continue, if they do that, they'd effectively be setting  `%username%` to nothing, i.e. undefining it. That would mean that you'd be running `net user /domain`, or it would if `%UserName%` wasn't an important system variable. You should fix that and change the variable's name to something else which isn't a system variable.

Answer (score 0):

No need for Powershell; just filter for the two lines, you want to display:

```
set /p "user=Enter Username: "
net user %user% | findstr /c:"Password Last Set" /c:"Password expires"
```

Note: `%username%` is a built-in variable that holds the name of the currently logged-in user. So you should use another variable name.